# Django heroku push gives could not build wheels for backports.zoneinfo error

Tags: python-3.x, django, heroku

I am trying to push a django project to heroku. heroku create worked fine but when trying to push to heroku main I get the following error.

'''

```
Enumerating objects: 5317, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5317/5317), done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (1852/1852), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5317/5317), 72.93 MiB | 134.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 5317 (delta 4004), reused 4506 (delta 3415)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> No Python version was specified. Using the buildpack default: python-3.10.4
remote:        To use a different version, see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote: -----> Installing python-3.10.4
remote: -----> Installing pip 21.3.1, setuptools 57.5.0 and wheel 0.37.0
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting asgiref==3.4.1
remote:          Downloading asgiref-3.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
remote:        Collecting backports.zoneinfo==0.2.1
remote:          Downloading backports.zoneinfo-0.2.1.tar.gz (74 kB)
remote:          Installing build dependencies: started
remote:          Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
remote:          Getting requirements to build wheel: started
remote:          Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
remote:          Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
remote:          Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
remote:        Collecting boto3==1.21.21
remote:          Downloading boto3-1.21.21-py3-none-any.whl (132 kB)
remote:        Collecting botocore==1.24.21
remote:          Downloading botocore-1.24.21-py3-none-any.whl (8.6 MB)
remote:        Collecting certifi==2021.10.8
remote:          Downloading certifi-2021.10.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (149 kB)
remote:        Collecting charset-normalizer==2.0.12
remote:          Downloading charset_normalizer-2.0.12-py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
remote:        Collecting click==8.0.4
remote:          Downloading click-8.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
remote:        Collecting cssselect==1.1.0
remote:          Downloading cssselect-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
remote:        Collecting Django==3.2.5
remote:          Downloading Django-3.2.5-py3-none-any.whl (7.9 MB)
remote:        Collecting django-autocomplete-light==3.9.4
remote:          Downloading django-autocomplete-light-3.9.4.tar.gz (168 kB)
remote:          Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
remote:          Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
remote:        Collecting django-bootstrap-pagination==1.7.1
remote:          Downloading django_bootstrap_pagination-1.7.1-py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
remote:        Collecting django-storages==1.12.3
remote:          Downloading django_storages-1.12.3-py3-none-any.whl (44 kB)
remote:        Collecting django-widget-tweaks==1.4.8
remote:          Downloading django_widget_tweaks-1.4.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
remote:        Collecting django-with-asserts==0.0.1
remote:          Downloading django-with-asserts-0.0.1.tar.gz (2.3 kB)
remote:          Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
remote:          Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
remote:        Collecting Faker==8.10.3
remote:          Downloading Faker-8.10.3-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
remote:        Collecting fontawesome-free==5.15.4
remote:          Downloading fontawesome_free-5.15.4-py3-none-any.whl (20.9 MB)
remote:        Collecting greenlet==1.1.2
remote:          Downloading greenlet-1.1.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (155 kB)
remote:        Collecting idna==3.3
remote:          Downloading idna-3.3-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
remote:        Collecting jmespath==1.0.0
remote:          Downloading jmespath-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
remote:        Collecting joblib==1.1.0
remote:          Downloading joblib-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (306 kB)
remote:        Collecting lxml==4.7.1
remote:          Downloading lxml-4.7.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.manylinux_2_24_x86_64.whl (6.9 MB)
remote:        Collecting Pillow==9.0.1
remote:          Downloading Pillow-9.0.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (4.3 MB)
remote:        Collecting libgravatar==1.0.0
remote:          Downloading libgravatar-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
remote:        Collecting nltk==3.7
remote:          Downloading nltk-3.7-py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
remote:        Collecting numpy==1.22.2
remote:          Downloading numpy-1.22.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (16.8 MB)
remote:        Collecting pandas==1.4.1
remote:          Downloading pandas-1.4.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (11.7 MB)
remote:        Collecting PyJWT==2.3.0
remote:          Downloading PyJWT-2.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
remote:        Collecting python-dateutil==2.8.2
remote:          Downloading python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (247 kB)
remote:        Collecting python-decouple==3.6
remote:          Downloading python_decouple-3.6-py3-none-any.whl (9.9 kB)
remote:        Collecting pytz==2021.1
remote:          Downloading pytz-2021.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510 kB)
remote:        Collecting requests==2.27.1
remote:          Downloading requests-2.27.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (63 kB)
remote:        Collecting s3transfer==0.5.2
remote:          Downloading s3transfer-0.5.2-py3-none-any.whl (79 kB)
remote:        Collecting regex==2022.3.15
remote:          Downloading regex-2022.3.15-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (763 kB)
remote:        Collecting scikit-learn==1.0.2
remote:          Downloading scikit_learn-1.0.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (26.5 MB)
remote:        Collecting scikit-surprise==1.1.1
remote:          Downloading scikit-surprise-1.1.1.tar.gz (11.8 MB)
remote:          Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
remote:          Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
remote:        Collecting scipy==1.8.0
remote:          Downloading scipy-1.8.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (42.3 MB)
remote:        Collecting six==1.16.0
remote:          Downloading six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
remote:        Collecting sklearn==0.0
remote:          Downloading sklearn-0.0.tar.gz (1.1 kB)
remote:          Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
remote:          Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
remote:        Collecting SQLAlchemy==1.4.31
remote:          Downloading SQLAlchemy-1.4.31-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (1.6 MB)
remote:        Collecting sqlparse==0.4.2
remote:          Downloading sqlparse-0.4.2-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
remote:        Collecting surprise==0.1
remote:          Downloading surprise-0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.8 kB)
remote:        Collecting tabulate==0.8.9
remote:          Downloading tabulate-0.8.9-py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
remote:        Collecting text-unidecode==1.3
remote:          Downloading text_unidecode-1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (78 kB)
remote:        Collecting threadpoolctl==3.1.0
remote:          Downloading threadpoolctl-3.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
remote:        Collecting tqdm==4.63.1
remote:          Downloading tqdm-4.63.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (76 kB)
remote:        Collecting urllib3==1.26.8
remote:          Downloading urllib3-1.26.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (138 kB)
remote:        Collecting coverage==6.1.1
remote:          Downloading coverage-6.1.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (215 kB)
remote:        Collecting gunicorn==20.1.0
remote:          Downloading gunicorn-20.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (79 kB)
remote:        Collecting django-on-heroku==1.1.2
remote:          Downloading django_on_heroku-1.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.1 kB)
remote:        Collecting whitenoise
remote:          Downloading whitenoise-6.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
remote:        Collecting psycopg2-binary
remote:          Downloading psycopg2_binary-2.9.3-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (3.0 MB)
remote:        Collecting dj-database-url>=0.5.0
remote:          Downloading dj_database_url-0.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.5 kB)
remote:        Building wheels for collected packages: backports.zoneinfo, django-autocomplete-light, django-with-asserts, scikit-surprise, sklearn
remote:          Building wheel for backports.zoneinfo (pyproject.toml): started
remote:          Building wheel for backports.zoneinfo (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
remote:          ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
remote:           command: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py build_wheel /tmp/tmp_65_48i9
remote:               cwd: /tmp/pip-install-pr_oku67/backports-zoneinfo_358c04e6bf0b4df0a6fdb4b542614e4a
remote:          Complete output (41 lines):
remote:          running bdist_wheel
remote:          running build
remote:          running build_py
remote:          creating build
remote:          creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10
remote:          creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/backports
remote:          copying src/backports/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/backports
remote:          creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/backports/zoneinfo
remote:          copying src/backports/zoneinfo/_version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/backports/zoneinfo
remote:          copying src/backports/zoneinfo/_common.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/backports/zoneinfo
remote:          copying src/backports/zoneinfo/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/backports/zoneinfo
remote:          copying src/backports/zoneinfo/_tzpath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/backports/zoneinfo
remote:          copying src/backports/zoneinfo/_zoneinfo.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/backports/zoneinfo
remote:          running egg_info
remote:          writing src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/PKG-INFO
remote:          writing dependency_links to src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
remote:          writing requirements to src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/requires.txt
remote:          writing top-level names to src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/top_level.txt
remote:          reading manifest file 'src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
remote:          reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
remote:          warning: no files found matching '*.png' under directory 'docs'
remote:          warning: no files found matching '*.svg' under directory 'docs'
remote:          no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
remote:          no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_output'
remote:          adding license file 'LICENSE'
remote:          adding license file 'licenses/LICENSE_APACHE'
remote:          writing manifest file 'src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
remote:          copying src/backports/zoneinfo/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/backports/zoneinfo
remote:          copying src/backports/zoneinfo/py.typed -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/backports/zoneinfo
remote:          running build_ext
remote:          building 'backports.zoneinfo._czoneinfo' extension
remote:          creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10
remote:          creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10/lib
remote:          gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python3.10 -c lib/zoneinfo_module.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10/lib/zoneinfo_module.o -std=c99
remote:          lib/zoneinfo_module.c: In function ‘zoneinfo_fromutc’:
remote:          lib/zoneinfo_module.c:600:19: error: ‘_PyLong_One’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘_PyLong_New’?
remote:            600 |             one = _PyLong_One;
remote:                |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~
remote:                |                   _PyLong_New
remote:          lib/zoneinfo_module.c:600:19: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
remote:          error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
remote:          ----------------------------------------
remote:          ERROR: Failed building wheel for backports.zoneinfo
remote:          Building wheel for django-autocomplete-light (setup.py): started
remote:          Building wheel for django-autocomplete-light (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
remote:          Created wheel for django-autocomplete-light: filename=django_autocomplete_light-3.9.4-py3-none-any.whl size=215911 sha256=30114df9dd68e354bfdb4d2f96e2021da6eb20671b65157403d780f499c26c8a
remote:          Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-r5m6o54r/wheels/ce/e8/3f/7e330eb9408b643697eb7512f5c489f6fcdf1aa0784b80bbcc
remote:          Building wheel for django-with-asserts (setup.py): started
remote:          Building wheel for django-with-asserts (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
remote:          Created wheel for django-with-asserts: filename=django_with_asserts-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl size=3412 sha256=578ae1491b724d413c91c83a05c2e97994ba1ccf881a69e1b84b9d0aa297c8c4
remote:          Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-r5m6o54r/wheels/7f/9b/7a/aad762caa70f6f9d09961c836bd7079372dd6624076b3aefec
remote:          Building wheel for scikit-surprise (setup.py): started
remote:          Building wheel for scikit-surprise (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
remote:          Created wheel for scikit-surprise: filename=scikit_surprise-1.1.1-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl size=2199346 sha256=ade1dd4c58dd83220e3f2f115582740c38ae1df7d75e9de17969eb73a978c3d7
remote:          Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-r5m6o54r/wheels/83/11/fb/6f834df4a72a79fcd80a6ab5e3098cee14dc66bda025915ace
remote:          Building wheel for sklearn (setup.py): started
remote:          Building wheel for sklearn (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
remote:          Created wheel for sklearn: filename=sklearn-0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl size=1309 sha256=5740fee80a0dfdf6c3e1b6f1fab7be2045f155cb4ff372a28671bdb3a6c71c99
remote:          Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-r5m6o54r/wheels/9b/13/01/6f3a7fd641f90e1f6c8c7cded057f3394f451f340371c68f3d
remote:        Successfully built django-autocomplete-light django-with-asserts scikit-surprise sklearn
remote:        Failed to build backports.zoneinfo
remote:        ERROR: Could not build wheels for backports.zoneinfo, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 19762dea9056f91bd1708c11f3c2b120b79f085c
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 19762dea9056f91bd1708c11f3c2b120b79f085c
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to [blocked].
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/[blocked].git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/[blocked].git'
```

'''

I tried looking for this error particular to heroku and couldn't find any solutions to it. I also tried installing backport.zoneinfo in my machine but it says requirements already satisfied.

I am new to heroku so any help would be appreciated. thank you.

Comment: it says blocked.  contact the administrator who can unblock.

Comment: https://github.com/pganssle/zoneinfo/issues/111

Comment: @phd thanks for the link..changing python version worked for me

Comment: Note that there is no *Git* issue here (there almost never is, with Heroku): Git is just a transport, bringing your commits to Heroku and then bringing Heroku's result (OK or error) back *to* you.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to a mismatch between your local python version and heroku's python runtime version being used which is python-3.10.4 as of now.

To specify which python runtime to use for heroku, create *runtime.txt* in your app's root directory and specify the exact python version. So if you do `cat runtime.txt`, it can look something like this

```
python-3.7.13
```

See [this webpage](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes) for more information.

As of now, supported python versions are

- python-3.10.3,
- python-3.9.11,
- python-3.8.13
- python-3.7.13

Comment: thank you for your answer. yes the python version was indeed the problem and specifying the version similar to my local machine in runtime.txt solved the issue